# Shuffling in Map-Reduce

Tags: java, mapreduce

I’m writing a map-reduce program in java (no Hadoop), just for exercise.
The classic word count.
Every Map (I have multiple maps running in parallel) produces a key-value data like this:
thanks, 1
java, 4
context, 1
you, 1
in, 2
…,…

Now I have to shuffle the maps results and send them to the reduce tasks and I’m not sure how to do so.
My first idea was to split the output of the map following the alphabet order, for example, the words starting from a to d sent to the first reducer. Words starting from e to h sent to the second reducer, and so on.

I’m not sure this is a good idea. The words distribution isn’t regular, so some reducer may receive more load than others. 
One solution maybe some sort of hash, in this is possible to use the hash of HashMap?

Are there some better methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hash function over the key value.
Something like this: 
`hc = k.hashCode();`.

hashCode return an Integer, its value span from negative numbers to positive numbers (Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE), so if you use it to compute an index value to call the a correct reduce function, use `hc = k.hashCode() & 0xffffffff`. The bitwise and function (&) mask the first bit, the bit sign.

No problem about hash collision (the hash return the same value for a different key), the important thing is to have the same hash for the same key.